# Counting letters in string regex

Tags: java, regex

i have a regex that is half working to count all strings which have odd numbers of X's.

```
^[^X]*X(X{2}|[^X])*$
```

This works for nearly all cases:

```
X
XXX
XAA
AXXX
AAAX etc
```

but fails when typing something like:

```
XAXAXA
```

I need an extra clause that allows for strings which have alternating X's that is XAXA. Contiguous X patterns are already being mapped by X{2}*.

Comment: You also need some way of handling odd runs of `X`, e.g. `AXXXAAXXX`.  But in short, I don't believe this task is possible.

Comment: Yeah infact any amount of letters diving  a single A from another A. It is definitely possible - i'm sure i've seen it before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regex matches string consisting of an uneven number of `X`'s:

```
^[^X]*(X[^X]*X[^X]*)*X[^X]*$
```

A quick break-down:

```
^          # the start of the input
[^X]*      # zero or more chars other than 'X'
(          # start group 1
  X[^X]*   #   an 'X' followed by zero or more chars other than 'X'
  X[^X]*   #   an 'X' followed by zero or more chars other than 'X'
)          # end  group 1
*          # repeat group 1 zero or more times
X          # an 'X'
[^X]*      # zero or more chars other than 'X'
$          # the end of the input
```

So, the repeated group 1 causes to match zero, or an even number of `X`'s to be matched, and the single `X` after is, makes it uneven.

Comment: +1: Nice!  I believe this should work (despite my dodgy intuition above that it's probably not possible).

Comment: wow great - is it possible to do it the other way round too? As in find an A, (A[^A]*A[^A])*

Comment: @dr85, sure, an `X` or an `A`, it doesn't really matter to the regex-engine.

Comment: sorry i wrote it badly. I mean your approach seems to find zero or more pairs of X's followed by non X's and then add an X at the end. is it possible to switch it so that it finds an X first, then adds the pair of X's. If you see what I mean?

Comment: @dr85, ah, I see. Sure, this one is equivalent: `^[^X]*X([^X]*X[^X]*X)*[^X]*$` (really a mirror image of my first suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

**Non-Regex Example**

This may be performance-hindering, but I am not sure if you are worried about that.

```
String str = "AXXXAXAXXX";
char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();
int count = 0;

for (char c : cArray)
{
    if (c == 'X')
        count++;
}

if (count % 2 != 0)
    //Odd
```

Comment: Performance wouldn't be hindered. Take a large enough string, and your suggestion be much, much faster than using regex. But my guess is that dr85 was just wondering how to do this in regex (I'm hoping s/he doesn't actually use it in his/her code!) :)

Comment: no way, i would always prefer this method. Im learning regexes at the minute and thats the only reason.

Answer (score 0):

try this, working fine for me
`^[^X]*((X[^X]*){2})*X[^X]*$`

tested against

```
X - match
XXX - match
XAA - match
AXXX - match
AAAX - match
XAXAXA - match
XXAAAAAX - match
AAXX - NO match
AAXXXXXXAX - match
```

Comment: This is merely a slightly condensed version of @Bart Kiers expression.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski, well, developed this alone but took me some time, @Bart Kiers was faster

Comment: Perhaps I was looking over your shoulder! :)